# driving distance using googleapis latitude and longitude not same as Google Maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

C# Visual Studio 2012

I'm using

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=29.695852,-91.223056&destination=,&mode=driving&sensor=true

to get driving distance between two locations.

But when I go to Google and enter the street addresses instead of latitude and longitude the distances are different enough to be concerned.

I used Google to get the latitude and longitudes in the first place.

Any idea what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess, but...  If the difference using latitude and longitude is always smaller, I would guess the answer is "a straight line is the shortest distance between two points".  The Google map distance is based on the driving distances and roads vary rarely go from point A to point B in a straight line.

Comment: After investigating I think that is correct. - Latitude and Longitude do not use streets.

Answer (score 0):

**You are missing the destinations parameters, like** `destination=29.695852,-91.223056`

Try this url - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=29.695852,-91.223056&destination=29.695852,-91.223056&mode=driving&sensor=true